# include two source directories not in the same folder structure in Maven

Tags: java, maven

I am trying to figure out how to include my common java directory into my Maven configuration. This is done outside an IDE, so Maven only.

The folder structure is
- Project1/src
- Project2/src

I have tried with

in the sourceDirectory I have added two directories.

```
<build>
        <sourceDirectory>src ../SGCommon/src</sourceDirectory>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src-common</directory>
                <excludes>
                    <exclude>**/*.java</exclude>
                </excludes>
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                    <archive>
            <manifest>
              <addClasspath>true</addClasspath>
              <mainClass>com.sg.intraday.Main</mainClass>
            </manifest>
          </archive>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: can you rephrase?

Comment: Why don't you follow conventions?